# How do you use session variables in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, variables

I have the following plugin: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-session-manager

I cannot work out how to use the session variables in WordPress. From what I understand by reading, this is how it should be used:

I have the following on page one (page 1):

```
global $wp_session;
$wp_session['loggedIn'] = 15;

echo $wp_session['loggedIn'];
```

On the first page, the session variable is working but on the second page, the session variable is not working.
Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: WordPress attempts to be *stateless*, and therefore actually *wipes* $_SESSION variables during part of it's load.  I have learned to use cookies instead inside of WP themes and plugins.

Comment: Thanks I have seen that written somewhere but don't have the time to learn to use the cookies at the moment. So just using the session manager plugin instead

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace:

```
global $wp_session;
```

With:

```
$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
```

Make sure you add `$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();` before you try to echo the variable on page 2.

Comment: Thanks that works exactly as I want it! Do you know how to end/destroy the wp_session? For example, I'm using it to log a user in, but how do I then logout and 'blank' the variable? Thanks :)

Comment: I suppose I could set it to "" and then just base my if statement to see if a user is logged in on that. if it = "" then show login page

Comment: If you get a chance, please see my post here with regards to this plugin.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878223/wordpress-wp-session-manager-variables-not-always-being-set

Thanks

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you, Nathan :-)

Answer (score 14):

1. Add below code in `function.php` file

```
function register_my_session(){
    if( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}

add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
```

2. After that you can store value in session variable like

```
$_SESSION['something'] = $xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

**Introducing WP_Session:**

Example :

```
global $wp_session;

$wp_session['user_name'] = 'User Name'; // A string

$wp_session['user_contact'] = array( 'email' => 'user@name.com' );// An array

$wp_session['user_obj'] = new WP_User( 1 ); // An object
```

**Wordpress session functions:**

1. wp_session_cache_expire() – get the session expiration time
2. wp_session_commit() – write session data out to the transient
3. wp_session_decode() – load data into the session from a serialized string
4. wp_session_encode() – write session data out to a serialized string
5. wp_session_regenerate_id() – change the ID of the current session to a new, random one
6. wp_session_start() – start the session and load data based on the user’s cookie
7. wp_session_status() – check the status of the current session
8. wp_session_unset() – clear out all variables in the current session
9. wp_session_write_close() – write session data and end session.

Comment: These are not native functions from WordPress and the plug-in that implements them has deprecated them. https://github.com/ericmann/wp-session-manager/blob/master/includes/deprecated.php