# WordPress: How can use $_SESSION in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have this code to select user country like this :-

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="countryname" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
<select>
```

Now I need to save the `countryname` in `$_SESSION` to use it in all my site page.

How can try this way in wordpress.

I f not support, How can set the page URL when select country to convert URL from

```
www.domain.com/
```

To

```
www.domain.com/?country=AD
```

To get it in `$_GET` value.

Comment: You can change <form method="post" as <form method="get"

Comment: @vural but when change URL its remove, So How cant remove it in URL  when change page

Comment: go to this link may you find your ans..
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811748/how-do-you-use-session-variables-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

in your page at the top you can start the session :-

```
session_start();
```

after that here you have a form with method POST.
So,whatever value get in  name="countryname" take this in Post method
like this:-

```
$country = $_POST['countryname'];
```

now your selected value store in $country ok.
after take this value in session like this:-

```
$_SESSION['country'] = $country
```

after that for check if in session value store or not

```
echo $_SESSION['country'];
```

and you get value in session

Answer (score 0):

Krunal Trivedi was right. You need on select organize the ajax call and post the countryname.  On server side you should take var from post and store at session

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="countryname" onchange="saveCountryCode()">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
<select>
```

jQuery Code:

```
function saveCountryCode(){
var selectedCountry = $('input[name="countryname"]').find(':selected').val();
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/countrySaver.php",
                data: { countryname: selectedCountry }

                }).done(function( result ) {
                        alert(result);
                });
}
```

countrySaver.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['countryname'] = $_POST['countryname'];
echo $_SESSION['countryname']
?>
```