# How to create Session in wordpress via laravel?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, session

I need to create session in wordpress by login in laravel. I have tried so many possiblities but invain.

Comment: Can you please be more specific in your question? Please elaborate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use session variables in wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811748/how-do-you-use-session-variables-in-wordpress)

Comment: this might help you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53503/can-i-programmatically-login-a-user-without-a-password

Comment: In wordpress there is dashboard. I create one custom dashboard by laravel. now want to login by laravel and want wordpress know that user is logged in, so that I can access everything which needed wordpress wp-admin login. how by laravel login wordpress know registered user is logged in. This is my question.

Comment: Any other clear solution plaese share, as i saw there is drawback with the above codes.

Answer (score -1):

Sessions aren't enabled in wordpress by default, if you want to add sessions in wordpress add this at the beginning of your **functions.php** :

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
```

You now can add values in session as `$_SESSION['your-variable'] = 'your-value';` .