# How to access PHP variable on every part of a wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

after hours to read docs about Wordpress I don't find how to get a code everywhere in my page (thew module, snippet or other).

In **functions.php**

```
<?php 
function foo_global() {
global $var;
$var = "foo";
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'foo_global' );
```

I want to access in different par of my page to $var (especially blocks).

I try thru xyz PHP Code module ou Code Snippets module, but that display nothing.

I don't understand where I'm wrong so anyhelp is welcome.

Comment: One of the common ways: enable session (in functions.php) in WP, then use session variables. For reference, see this [SO_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811748/how-do-you-use-session-variables-in-wordpress)

Comment: I thought it's a little bit dirty and I don't need that all the pages, but it works. Thanks

Comment: Another way which doesn't persist the value when you change page is `$_GLOBALS`.

Comment: Yes it's far better in ly opinion