# Wordpress PHP using global constants to avoid hard-coded values

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing on a Wordpress website with my own php coding. So far I am using the Snippets plugin which I like most for adding PHP code to existing wordpress sites.

The only thing I would like to know is how i can use something like global constants to avoid hard-coded values. Because I am using the same values again and again. What is the best way?

Thank you for any help.
best,

Comment: One of the common ways: enable session (in functions.php) in WP, then use session variables. For reference, see this [SO_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811748/how-do-you-use-session-variables-in-wordpress)

Comment: Sorry, but this question is off-topic here.  [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically - asking questions that would be answered with opinions. Instead, please try to better describe your problem and what you have done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to create your own global variables on Wordpress ([read this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89263/how-to-set-and-use-global-variables-or-why-not-to-use-them-at-all)). But you you can achieve this by defining global variables.

```
function my_globals() {
        global $myglobals;
        // We define it as an array so you can store multiple values. If only needed one value you can directly set it 
        $myglobals = array();
        $myglobals['first'] = 'This is first content';
        $myglobals['second'] = 'This is second content';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_globals' );
```

Now you can call your global using:

```
global $myglobals;
echo $myglobal['first'];
echo $myglobal['last'];
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89263/how-to-set-and-use-global-variables-or-why-not-to-use-them-at-all

Comment: Thanks @HowardE, included in the answer